# Sqlite works in simulator but not in device in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am using Sqlite in my app to save data. Code is working fine in Simulator but crashes in real device. Here is my code

```
 NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDriectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * path = [documentDriectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foodtruckfinder.sqlite"];

if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlquery = "select * from favorites";
    sqlite3_stmt * search_stmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlquery,-1, &search_stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(search_stmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString * idStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 0)];
            NSString * user_idStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 1)];
            NSString * latiStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 2)];
            NSString * longiStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 3)];
            NSString * useremailStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 4)];
            NSString * facebStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 5)];
            NSString * twittStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 6)];
            NSString * instagStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 7)];
            NSString * phoneNumberStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 8)];
            NSString * truckNameStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 9)];
            NSString * truckEmailStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 10)];
            NSString * truckDescStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 11)];
            NSString * websiteUrlStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 12)];
            NSString * endTimeStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(search_stmt, 13)];

        }else {
            NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(search_stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

It shows me "Unknown error" in device. I can't understand why it is not working in device. can anyone help me in this?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @AshishKakkad I am getting "Unknown error"

Comment: your "foodtruckfinder.sqlite" is not there in Document Directory of device. first you have to put there and than get it by it's path.  Check for NSString * path = [documentDriectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foodtruckfinder.sqlite"];

Comment: Can you try by completing remove app from device and reinstall?

Comment: I am getting path :- /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31492C1D-17EF-4C64-B1E7-7C81027EDBE0/Documents/foodtruckfinder.sqlite  The problem is it never goes in  if(sqlite3_step(search_stmt)==SQLITE_ROW){  }

Comment: Have you spelt `favorites` correctly, i.e. is that how its spelt in the database? and not `favourites`. Also not a good idea to do `Select *`, you should really specify the columns you want so that the code that pulls out the data is getting the correct column

Comment: Yes, it spelt correctly. Don't know how, but it is working fine in simulator but not in real device.

Comment: Is the file name the same case, i.e. on the device is the file name all lowercase?